# OpenSSL get's the server SSL key instead of the website SSL key

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

If I navigate to my site, it shows in the browser that my ssl key is correct for my site hosted at WP Engine. It is showing and validating my certificate. However, if I connect with openssl, it get's the underlying servers ssl key.

openssl s_client -connect mysite.com:443

How do I get the SSL command to resolve the ssl key using the domain name instead of the ip address only.

This isn't a WP Engine issue. I have reproduced it on Amazon servers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `-servername` option to `openssl s_client`, because your SSL termination device is using SNI (Server Name Indication).